# how does lxml module access the internet?

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests, lxml

someone knows how does lxml module goes to the internet?

im pulling data from website to excel via 'pandas'.

i understand that pandas get to the url by lxml module.

someone knows how lxml  get to the internet? by 'requests'? cant find the code

my code -

```
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd


tickers = ['TSLA', 'TWTR', 'MSFT', 'GOOG', 'AAPL']
interval = '1d'
period1 = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1).timetuple()))
period2 = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2022, 6, 30).timetuple()))


xlwriter = pd.ExcelWriter('historical prices.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

for ticker in tickers:
    query_string = f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1={period1}&period2={period2}&interval={interval}&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'
    df = pd.read_csv(query_string)
    df.to_excel(xlwriter, sheet_name=ticker, index=False)

xlwriter.save()
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not using lxml. It depend what you are trying to read if it's a csv/xml/html/json and so on. Lxml it's using for parsing and not for retrieving the file.

When you are using an url  it will use the function `_get_filepath_or_buffer` that you  can find [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/common.py#L284)

Here the [the link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/io/common.py#L361).

You will find in the souce code

```py
        import urllib.request

        # assuming storage_options is to be interpreted as headers
        req_info = urllib.request.Request(filepath_or_buffer, headers=storage_options)
        with urlopen(req_info) as req:
            content_encoding = req.headers.get("Content-Encoding", None)
            if content_encoding == "gzip":
                # Override compression based on Content-Encoding header
                compression = {"method": "gzip"}
            reader = BytesIO(req.read())
```